# Is the reversible process possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, reversibility

When I was studying about heat engine, specifically [Carnot cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_cycle), I though the assumptions to be impossible. Then why one should study all these? What would reversibility mean in reality?

Comment: The Second Law of Thermodynamics pretty much states perfectly reversible processes are impossible. At a quantum level, however, short-term repeatable processes might occur, but at low probability and not in a controllable way.

Comment: Practically Second Law of Thermodynamic is also impossible in some way but still it have some sort of application in Physics and that's why we study it. And same is the case with the Carnot Engine.

Comment: Massless ropes, frictionless planes, massless pulleys,...

Answer (score 4):

This is a very important question, thermodynamics strictly speaking only applies to quasistatic processes. E.g. if heat is transferred from one system to another one, then that process is necessarily an out of equilibrium process during which you cannot rigorously define thermodynamic variables like temperature (not just one temperature for the entire system, obviously you would want to describe this using two temperatures, but even that is not possible). Only when the process happens infinitely slowly, is a thermodynamic description of the heat transfer process possible.

As Frederick Reif says in [his book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1577666127), thermodynamics is a misnomer, the subject should have been called "thermostatics". So, how can be that thermodynamics is such a useful subject and used by engineers to describe real physical processes when the theory itself says that it only applies to static equilibrium situations?

The reason why you can use thermodynamics in practice is because in many cases it suffices to consider initial and final states that are in thermal equilibrium. So, in a Carnot-like process that is not an ideal reversible Carnot process, you can still consider a rigorously defined initial state where you have two objects that are at different temperatures and the heat engine in a well defined thermodynamic state. And you can consider a final state with the machine in the same state as in the initial state and the two objects in well defined thermal equilibrium states but now at different temperatures compared to their initial temperatures.

Work and heat are well defined from only the initial and final states. Work is defined as the change in internal energy due to a change in the external parameters and this does not require that there be a thermodynamic description of the process. Heat is defined as the part of the change in internal energy that is not due to work. The First Law of thermodynamics is thus a trivial consequence of conservation of energy.

Another important aspect of thermodynamics is that the way you can define the system is entirely subjective, which allows you some flexibility to be able to describe processes that are out of equilibrium. E.g. if you have two systems each of which is in thermal equilibrium but at different temperatures, then the system comprising of both of them is not in thermal equilibrium and thus cannot be described by a single temperature.

You can then ask if you can reverse this process, where an out of equilibrium system can be considered as a collection of subsystems that are each in internal thermal equilibrium but not in equilibrium with each other. In general this doesn't work, but to a good approximation you can usually describe an object like a gas that is not in thermal equilibrium as being in "local thermal equilibrium". You then assume that there exists a position dependent temperature, pressure etc. To a first approximation you can capture all the effects of the non-equilibrium using so-called transport coefficients like heat conducion coefficient, viscosity, etc. that describes how the system wants to relax back to global thermal equilibrium.

That such a description is not exactly valid becomes clear if you attempt to compute the transport parameters from first principles. You'll find that if you assume that each point really has a locally well defined temperature, then you would not have any heat conduction, so the heat conduction coefficient should be zero. It is only nonzero because the local velocity distribution is not given exactly by the Maxwell Boltzmann velocity distribution corresponding to the local temperature (or for that matter any temperature).

Comment: I would just like to confirm that when heat is being transferred from a system during which one cannot define thermodynamic variable because they ( temperature , pressure) are changing. So we don't have a unique( single value) variable. But can we not  define the variables for an infinitesimally small time interval over which temperature stays constant ?

Comment: Suppose that you have a gas in one container that is very slowly cooling. Suppose that we pretend that the gas in the container can be described exactly as in thermal equilibrium but now with a gradually decreasing temperature. If that were exactly true then at any time the velocity distribution of the molecules would be exactly given by the Maxwell distribution where you now replace the constant temperature by the time dependent slowly decreasing temperature. But then at any give moment in time you have a Maxwell distribution and in such a distribution you don't have a net energy flux.

Comment: So, if in some approximate sense you have a notion of a changing temperature due to heat flow, you must also have a (small) deviation of the Maxwell velocity distribution allowing for that heat flow to exist, so even in some snapshot picture at some fixed time the system isn't exactly describable by a temperature.

Comment: Thanks ! I almost understood everything up till the sentence that we will have to replace the constant temperature by time dependent temperature in Maxwell distribution , but just couldn't understand the line following it. Are Maxwell Distribution derives for equilibrium ( no heat flow ) state. I have read the distribution just thermodynamics .

Comment: @Shashaank So, in a gas in thermal equilibrium there is no heat flow. Now the heat flow is completely determined by the velocity distribution as a function of position. So, specifying  that the number of molecules within a volume $d^3x$ of some position $x$ and a volume element in "velocity space" $d^3 v$ of some velocity $v$ is $N f(x,v)d^3x d^3v$ where $N$ is the total number of molecules, completely fixes what the net transport of heat is. If you then take this $f(x,v)$ to be what it is in thermal equilibrium at some temperature, i.e. independent of position and of Maxwell form

Comment: then there is no heat flow. You can also see that given some arbitrary $f(x,v)$ fixes the way this function changes in time, so you cannot just write down some arbitrary time dependent distribution function, it has to satisfy the [Boltzmann transport equation](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/franz.vesely/sp_english/sp/node7.html).

Comment: Ok I begin to see things. Just like Kirchoff law , Stefan law are  meant for equilibrium analysis so is this. I begin to see why it comes from Maxwell's Law. But does that mean that all the laws 1st law 2nd law ( or if they are applicable then please tell which are not)are applicable at equilibrium.....I mean if yes or no then where would we go wrong in applying  the law. What would be the fault in the analysis. I see things from the Distribution law just you said but can't develop the physical intuition . Thank you for helping !

Comment: Also can you refer a book in which sort these types of nice subtilities are proven nively

Comment: @Shashaank The book by Reif https://www.amazon.com/dp/1577666127 is a good book, he takes it slowly starting from the basic concepts in equilibrium statistical mechanics all the way to advanced non-equilibrium stuff.