# Energy conservation and the 1st law of thermodynamics with external forces

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-fields, work, kinetic-theory, gas

I have a box filled with a gas ( a real gas , cannot be approximated to a ideal gas) in which the molecules are jiggling. This box is in a gravitational field and an electric field  and has a piston over it. The piston is not diathermal and the gas is somehow doing work on the piston. Together with this , the box is moving in the gravitational field as well as the electric field and there is an external force on the box which is continuously accelerating it.  Moreover outside the box there is some medium which is applying a non conservative force on the box as it moves ( friction ).

What would be the 1st law in this case for the entire box piston system. I am not asking for a solution ( it might not be possible ). I am asking what the general equation of the 1st law would become ( just the terms that would be added ) due to gravitational , electric and non conservative force effect. What shall be the energy Conservation equation in the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the complete form of the first law of thermodynamics (that is sometimes overlooked) is $$\Delta E=Q-W$$where $$E=U+(KE)+(PE)$$  Also, in this equation, W includes piston work, frictional work, work related to an electric field, etc.  The system, according to your description includes the solid box and its contents (the gas).  Actually, the electric field could be lumped in with the PE or it could be included separately in the work.  But the PE would usually be considered to include gravitational.

Comment: Thanks I was in search for the answer since weeks. The problem that I had was that U (internal energy) , according to wikipedia does not depend  on external fields ( electric or any other ). So please just tell whether what I have understood from your answer is correct ! The U term in your equation accounts for the internal energy ( depending on only internal forces and accounting for the K.E due to random motion of molecules which the gives the gas its temperature) . I am continuing in the comment (just a second)

Comment: Continued- The KE and PE terms include the kinetic and the potential energy of the system due to its movement in the field ( electric gravitational ). For W you have explained already. Now if this is right , then first of all due to Movement of the system in the field and due to the continued work done by the external force its PE and KE will continuously change . How to represent that ?Thanks

Comment: Well, to determine the changes in KE and PE, you usually also have to use Newton's 2nd law (unless you are provided with more specific details on the initial and final states of the system).

Comment: So at any instant of time where I know the values of P.E & Ke the equation is the above one ?  Besides that + W would be equally right ?  And just one last thing . Wouldn't the KE term and PE term have any effect on U ( relative motion for K.E polarization effects for P.E ) ? In that way U would depend on external field but wiki media says it doesn't ?

Comment: I don't have experience with applying this in situations where there is an electric field or a magnetic field, but my inclination would be to include molecular polarization effects in the internal energy.  I might also add that, if the final state of the system is not an equilibrium state (such that the KE , pressure, temperature, etc. of the gas is changing), you would supplement this with consideration of the fluid mechanics of the gas (including viscous effects and turbulence).

Comment: Thanks ! I start getting it now . But the above equation in your answer is always correct , right ? The equation is correct in whatever case we apply the solutions will change . The equation is correct that's 100 % , right ?

Comment: That equation is straight out of Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van Ness.

Comment: Ok! Thanks  ! Will have a look at the book . Probably it will help in learning thermodynamics this semester !

Comment: Another book I highly recommend is Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al

Comment: Oh ! Thanks for the recommendation. Will try to find a PDF of these. Actually in Enrico Fermi's book on thermodynamics there is just a line regarding the fact that the systems under consideration don't move in an external field. Like you said most of the physics books that I have don't deal with this. Can I find this ( sort of detailed description in these books ). And also can you recommend a book on thermodynamics  for a physics undergrad for conceptual understanding. Because I didn't find Sears and Salinger very beneficial. Or the above would sufficient for complete learning

Comment: Sorry for asking again but can you just help with me with this .......I wanted to ask that we read that temperature is due to random internal kinetic energy. Is temperature also due to the internal potential energy or the total internal energy or only because of kinetic energy. Thank you !

Comment: My understanding is that temperature is only due to internal kinetic energy, and not internal potential energy.

Comment: Ok Thank you for the help. I will separately post a question on Stack as to why potential energy and rotational internal energy don't contribute to temperature because atleast vibrational should. We use it in specific heat models. And another on Regarding "How Much of Thermodynamics is applicable only at equilibrium " after the answer and comments therein http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/145570/113699 Thank you !

Comment: This is a thermodynamics question which I asked last year. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/277033/113699 . But I am still not clear on it. Its long because it contains my reasoning ( in bold ) which is the main doubt. Could you please , if you wish have a look at it and help  me in it. Its over half n year now. Still struggling with that question. Thank You !

Comment: I got back to this question while reviewing.. I had just a small doubt..if you could enlightem me a bit it would be great. .. The W on the RHS includes both the work the external done on the whole system which increases KE and piston work... But according to mechanics work done on a system increases its KE but in the expression for thermodynamical work ( which is also included in above expression for W) i.e. PdV, it doesn't increase the KE of the system. It doesn't make the system move out or rise or change it's KE. .. So what I am missing

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  But, definitely, the W on the RHS does not include KE.  It only includes piston work, i.e., force times displacement.  Where did you ever learn that W and KE are the same thing?

Comment: no no that's not what I am saying. Please bear with my long explanation. From mechanics Work don't on system= change of KE of it. Consider a box with gas at REST where the gas can push a piston. 1st law in this case - dU= dQ-dW' where dW' = PdV ( thermodynamical work). But here the work done does not change the KE of the system, which it should by laws of mechanics, that's the doubt. Now take the same box with piston doing work but now the box accelerates due an external force F(ext) ans is under the effect of gravity and electric field which do work W(g) and W(e) respectively.

Comment: now the 1st law according to your eqn shoud be -> dU + d(KE) = dQ - dW' + dW+ dW(g) + dW(e) which is alternatively equal to ( since dW(g) = -d(PE(g)) etc.) -> dU +d(KE) + d(PE(g)) +d(PE(e)) = dQ - dW' + dW, where dW is the work done due to external force F(e) and d(KE) is the change in KE due to work of all forces ( work energy theorem) and dW' is the work done on piston  like before. I am asking Firstly, 1) Are the above 1st law eqns correct or not, if wrong pls let me know separately 2) dW' is not producing a change in KE which it should by work energy theorem..

Comment: I think I got the answer... The dW' part is changing the internal energy and internal energy is a form of KE of gas molecules. As far as the 2nd ques, I guess my eqns look correct. Could you confirm pls..

Comment: I am unable to make sense out of what you are saying.  But basically, it  is nothing more complicated than the Answer I gave.  Also, U is random molecular kinetic energy plus potential energy of molecular interactions while KE is separate and equal to organized kinetic energy, determined by the velocity averaged vectorially over all the molecules.

Comment: I am just asking if  the entire box with the gas is pushed by me by applying a mechanical force which consequently does work W on the box, then is the work done by this mechanical force included in "Work Done" on the R. H. S of the 1st law eqn that you have written or not. Is the work done by me on the box by applying a force included on the R. H. S of the eqn or not.... I hope I have been able to express the ques properly this time... Pls let me know..

Comment: If the system is the gas, and we neglect the mass of the box itself, then the force you are exerting on the box is transmitted by the box to the gas, and this force is being applied through a displacement, so, yes, that is included in W.

Comment: yep that makes it clear.. And what if the system is the box + gas and the box has mass so that there is a finite change in the KE of the box itself by the force that I have applied then will this work done by the force that I have applied on the box + gas system be included in the "W" on the R. H. S or not.. ..other things clear.. Just will in this case the work done by me on the total  system be included on the R. H. S or not... This is what I was trying to say earlier. Pls let me this.

Comment: Then in E, you need to include the KE and U of the box itself.

Comment: Yes now it's clarified.. Thanks for confirming...